# Как реализовать редактирование данных выбранного пользователя через форму редактирования на JS или JQuery?

Tags: javascript

Прошу помощи. Лучше, если зададите направление.

Дана таблица пользователей с персональными данными типа: ФИО, дата рождения и т.д. У каждого пользователя есть две кнопки: удалить и редактировать.

При удалении я использую делегирование, чтобы отлавливать "Пользователя", которого решили удалить. Вылетает кастомная модалка, дабы подтвердить действие. И тут возникает проблема.

Суть проблемы: я навешиваю обработчик на кнопку "подтверждения" модалки внутри выполнения обработчика кнопки удаления. То есть:

1. Нажимаю удалить, вылазит модалка. Я просто её закрываю, типа передумал.
2. Нажимаю удалить на другом элементе и подтверждаю. Удаляются два элемента. Тот, что открывал прежде и текущий.

Так не следует делать и я это понимаю. Но не могу продумать, как тогда удалить элемент после нажатия кнопки подтвердить?

Ведь когда я обрабатываю клик по нажатию кнопки удалить, он находит нужный мне элемент, так как кнопка удалить является дочерним элементом столбца с пользователем.

А вот кнопка подтверждения таковой не является и я не могу получить элемент по event.target

```
_setEventListener() {
$('.user-table').on('click', '.button_delete', (event) => {
  // получаем елемент строки текущего юзера
  const element = event.target.closest('.user-table__row');
  // получаем ID юзера, присвоенный при создании в data-аргумент
  const currentUserID = element.getAttribute('data-userid');

   $(this.confirmBtn).on('click', () => {
    // удаляем юзера из БД по ID
    this.firebase.deleteUser(currentUserID);
    // удаляем из DOM
    element.remove(); // как раз тот элемент, который я нахожу во время обработки клика
    this.popupConfirmCloseMethod();
  })
});
```

}

Прошу прощения за, возможно, коряво составленный вопрос. Грамотно составлять вопросы оказалось целой наукой, которую я только начал постигать. И за то, что где-то использую Jquery, где-то нет. Только его постигаю впопыхах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вешайте на кнопку закрытия модалки функцию, делающую `$(this.confirmBtn).off('click')` , тогда будут сниматься лишние остающиеся обработчики.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш метод решения данной проблемы. Я уже решил немного другим способом. Однако, ваш метод тоже рабочий.

Answer (score 0):

Я решил данный момент простым присваиванием обработчика DOM елементу:

```
this.confirmBtn.onclick = () => {
    // удаляем юзера из БД по ID
    this.firebase.deleteUser(currentUserID);
    // удаляем из DOM
    element.remove(); 
    this.popupConfirmCloseMethod();
  }
```

Так как у элемента DOM может быть только одно свойство с именем onclick, то назначить более одного обработчика так нельзя. Отсюда всё работает корректно.